# Crash Error Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdlXXXXXXXXXX.tmp Android Play Store Release using Expo EAS

Tags: react-native, expo, crash, eas, opendir

I have released a number of versions of my app using Expo Managed development to both the Play Store and the App store.  All were done using an earlier version of Expo CLI. Because of Google requirements, I was forced to upgrade. I haven't been able to release a version that gets beyond the splash screen since to Play Store or App Store .

My app runs fine using the expo dev client. It also runs fine when you start it as if it were a production release.

npx expo start --no-dev --minify

I have followed Expo's "instructions" to the T as much as I understand of how to create a release for the app stores.

Here are the first errors in LogCat. Can someone at least address the first problem. There is a stackOverflow problem that reports my first error but his solution doesn't apply since I am using EAS to build and don't have a build.graedle file.

Thanks in advance for your help

10-02 18:57:16.247: E/installd(926): Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl2140974827.tmp: No such file or directory
10-02 18:57:16.247: E/installd(926): Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl2140974827.tmp: No such file or directory
10-02 18:57:16.300: E/.apps.wellbeing(17148): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
10-02 18:57:16.325: E/VvmPkgInstalledRcvr(2944): cannot create TelephonyManager from ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, E, UserHandle{0
10-02 18:57:16.407: E/e.android.euicc(17186): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
10-02 18:57:16.538: E/Finsky(15109): [70] ryv.a(110): ItemStore: getItems RPC failed.
10-02 18:57:16.638: E/AppOps(1435): Bad call made by uid 10126. Package "com.google.android.gms" does not belong to uid 10126.
10-02 18:57:16.981: E/VerityUtils(1435): Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~-IQEvKf5pqPV3lZEy0Gcuw==/com.google.android.gms.policy_test_support-HEDqKeH_RryzpkwKd6NwlQ==/base.apk
10-02 18:57:17.688: E/DowngradeHelper(16990): isModuleDowngradeRequired false
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318): Phenotype API error. Event # egrr@93cda9be, EventCode: 5 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318): bykk: 29501: Stale snapshot for com.google.android.gms.phenotype(change count changed - expected 4  but was 3)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318): bykk: 29501: Stale snapshot for com.google.android.gms.phenotype(change count changed - expected 4  but was 3)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at byls.b(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):824)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at bylq.g(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):3)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at byln.e(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):18)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at byln.f(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):5)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at awnm.eu(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):1)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at awnt.run(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):146)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at difl.run(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):13)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at acse.c(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):50)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at acse.run(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):76)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at acxm.run(:com.google.android.gms@232617044@23.26.17 (190400-551657477):8)
10-02 18:57:17.787: E/byln(14318):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)